# Injecting a Spring bean using CDI @Inject

Tags: java, spring, jsf, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm trying to inject a bean defined in a Spring context into a CDI managed component but I'm not successful. The bean is not injected, instead a new instance gets created each time the injection should be performed. My environment is Tomcat 7 with JBoss Weld.

The Spring ApplicationContext is straighforward:

```
<beans>
  ...
  <bean id="testFromSpring" class="test.Test" />
  ...
</bean>
```

The CDI managed bean looks like this:

```
@javax.inject.Named("testA")
public class TestA {

  @javax.inject.Inject
  private Test myTest = null;

  ...

  public Test getTest() {
    return this.myTest;
  }

}
```

This is my `faces-config.xml`

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

However, when I access the `test` property from within a JSF page, a new `Test` instance is being created each time the access occurs. This is a simple example:

```
<html>
  ...
  <p>1: <h:outputText value="#{testFromSpring}" /></p>
  <p>2: <h:outputText value="#{testA.test}" /></p>
  ...
```

I get the following output:

```
1: test.Test@44d79c75
2: test.Test@53f336eb
```

After a refresh:

```
1: test.Test@44d79c75
2: test.Test@89f2ac63
```

I can see that the first output is correct. No matter how often I refresh the page, the `testFromSpring` returns the value from the bean defined in the Spring context. However the second output clearly shows that each time the `getTest` method on the `test` components is invoked, a new `Test` instance is created and injected instead of using the instance from the Spring context as I would expect.

So, what's the reason for this behaviour?

How can I inject the bean from the Spring context into the CDI managed bean?

I also tried using a qualifier using the name defined in the Spring context, but now an exception is thrown indicating, that the bean cannot be found:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Injection point has unsatisfied dependencies.  Injection point:  field test.TestA.myTest;  Qualifiers:  [@javax.inject.Named(value=testFromSpring)]
```

for the code

```
@javax.inject.Named("testA")
public class TestA {

  @javax.inject.Inject
  @javax.inject.Named("testFromSpring")
  private Test myTest = null;
```

Comment: This could be lack of coffee here, but why inject a private member of your class (that is already set to null).  Would it not be simpler to provide myTest as part of TestA's constructor (e.g.  Constructor injection)

Comment: The injection is just an example and not the point of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pascal is right that you can't inject something managed by spring into a weld bean (or vice-versa).

But you can define a producer that gets spring beans and gives them to Weld. This sounds like an extreme hack, btw, and I don't think you are supposed to use both frameworks in one project. Choose one and remove the other. Otherwise you'll get in multiple problems.

Here's how it would look like.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(Runtime)
public @interface SpringBean {
     @NonBinding String name();
}


public class SpringBeanProducer {

    @Produces @SpringBean
    public Object create(InjectionPoint ip) {
         // get the name() from the annotation on the injection point
         String springBeanName = ip.getAnnotations()....

         //get the ServletContext from the FacesContext
         ServletContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()... 

         return WebApplicationContextUtils
              .getRequiredWebApplication(ctx).getBean(springBeanName);
    }
}
```

Then you can have:

```
@Inject @SpringBean("fooBean")
private Foo yourObject;
```

P.S. You can make the above more type-safe. Instead of getting the bean by name, you can get, through reflection, the generic type of the injection point, and look it up in the spring context.

Comment: You cannot produce Object and match with Foo injection point in CDI

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Weld can inject something that is not managed (instantiated) by Weld (a Spring bean in your case).

Answer (score 2):

There's also the JBoss Snowdrop project. I don't know if it'll work with JBoss Weld on Tomcat, the documentation describes only on JBoss 5, 6 and 7. According to http://docs.jboss.org/snowdrop/2.0.0.Final/html/ch03.html#d0e618 it will inject beans declared in jboss-spring.xml into locations marked with @Spring instead of @Inject. No experience myself though, YMMV.