# spring,jsf and hibernate application : controller and managedbean approch

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

What is the difference beetween implementing a spring,jsf and hibernate application  using managedbean and controller.

I'm working on a project using spring hibernate controller approach and i whould to integrate the jsf to handle the view part but it's unclear for me how to deal with controller and managedbean at the same time because they both happen to have nearly the same role .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is if you want to use JSF use Java EE. If you are sticking with Spring-mvc then use Jquery etc. However checkout the following links:

[Spring 4 and JSF In](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-jsf-2-integration-example-using-autowired-annotation)

[JSF 2.2, Spring 4 and CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391332/jsf-2-2-and-spring-4-and-cdi-on-different-layers-without-losing-spring-features)