# Spring 5.x and CDI 2.x Integration Options

Tags: java, spring, integration, cdi

Considering Spring's 5.x baseline and CDI's baseline 2.x, what more viable options should I consider to integrate them into a project with JSF 2.3, since JSF 2.3 is coupled with the CDI? Bridges? Custom Bean Factories? Others?

Comment: JSF 2.3 should still work without CDI but it will be required dependency in the future. So the question is why do you need Spring? If you really need it, i would build my view beans with CDI and get a extensions which can inject Spring beans into CDI.

Comment: Thanks by comment. Spring, the regular stack of organization, it's a requirement of project. I'm searching a extension that can be used actually. Projects like apache delta spike addons([link](https://github.com/os890/ds-spring-bridge-addon)) and spring-cid-bridge([link](https://github.com/rmannibucau/cdi-spring-bridge)) appears outdated.

Resources as flow-scope(JSF 2.2) and websocket(JSF 2.3) are tied to CDI and appears that the mojarra JSF 2.3 with Servlet 4.0+ requires CDI.

Comment: I would use CDI for the view then and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144039/injecting-a-spring-bean-using-cdi-inject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use bean producers to access Spring objects in CDI. As in the architecture we used there is an interface layer between the UI and the server/business, this integration was facilitated.
Integration is performed as follows.

Cdi Factory from the view/ui layer.

```
public class MainViewClientFactory {

    public MainViewClientFactory() {
    }

    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    public CadastroPaisService cadastroPaisService() {
        return CdiSpringUtils.getSpringBean(CadastroPaisService.class);
    }

}
```

The CdiSpringUtils Class.

```
public class CdiSpringUtils {

    private CdiSpringUtils() {
    }

    public static <R, Q extends Annotation> R getSpringBean(Class<R> beanClass) {
        return ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(beanClass);
    }

    public static <R, Q extends Annotation> R getSpringBean(Class<R> beanClass, Class<Q> qualifierClass) {
        return ApplicationContextProvider.getQualifiedBeanOfType(beanClass, qualifierClass);
    }

}
```

The ApplicationContextProvider Class.

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static <R, Q extends Annotation> R getQualifiedBeanOfType(Class<R> cls, Class<Q> qualifierAnnotationClass) {
        R bean = null;
        Map<String, R> beanMap = getApplicationContext().getBeansOfType(cls);
        for (Map.Entry<String, R> entry : beanMap.entrySet()) {
            Q targetAnnotation = getApplicationContext().findAnnotationOnBean(entry.getKey(), qualifierAnnotationClass);
            if (targetAnnotation != null) {
                bean = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```